# Parsing XML data from SOAP response with AJAX in IE9, unable to get values of child nodes

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, soap

I'm using AJAX to parse a SOAP response from a web service, and it's working just fine in Firefox and Chrome. However, in IE8 and 9,I am unable to access the values of the child nodes under the 'votes' node.

Sample xml:

```
<ns1:getvotesResponse>
<arg1/>
<arg2/>
<arg3/>
<locID>0371</locID>
<votes>
    <candidateone>131013</candidateone>
    <candidatetwo>8079</candidatetwo>
    <candidateonestart>632</candidateonestart>
    <candidatetwostart>53</candidatetwostart>
    <candidateonespeed>0.001</candidateonespeed>
    <candidatetwospeed>0.0005</candidateonespeed>
</votes>
</ns1:getvotesResponse>
```

I've tried all manner of code to try to get the values from any of the nodes under 'votes', but IE simply will not display them.

Example: one of the responses I found here stated to use this:

```
var xmlText = $(envObj).find("soap\\:Envelope").find("soap\\:Body").find("getvotesResponse").find("votes").find("candidateone").text();
```

- which returns nothing when I print the value of xmlText to the console.

I have also tried this:

```
console.log(envObj.votes);
```

- which returns all of the values of the child nodes in one long value, like so: 1310138079632530.0010.0005

How would I be able to parse out each of the values of the child nodes separately, so that I can pass them as parameters?

Comment: Did you create `envObj` using `$.parseXML(xmlstring)`? or is it a response from an ajax request with `dataType: "xml"`? Basically I'm confirming that you are working with an `XMLDocument` and not an `DOMFragment`.

Comment: It's a response from an ajax request using xml datatype.